Can a UNIDRV plugin display notifications?
Can a UNIDRV plugin display notifications
(e.g., "Printer is powered off, please connect and plug in USB")?

I've noticed that some printers can show notifications or message boxes.
I would like to implement something similar.
I'm writing UNIDRV rendering plugin minidriver.
My MessageBox code in user mode can successfully display message boxes or tooltips.
(ex. MessageBox(title, message, MB_OK);)
However, the same code in the UNIDRV plugin doesn't show anything.(in kernel mode)
How can I display notifications or message boxes UNIDRV plugin( in kernel mode)?
(ex. in OEMStartDoc or OEMEndDoc)
///////////////////////////////////////////
I have tried CreateProcess of snoretoast.exe.
CreateProcess executed in kernel mode also fails to display tooltips, just like other methods

GitHub: https://github.com/KDE/snoretoast
  bool RunToast(const std::wstring& title, const std::wstring& message) 
    {
            
        std::wstring commandLine = L"snoretoast.exe -t \"" + title + L"\" -m \"" + message + L"\" -b OK";
        
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
        
        if (!CreateProcess(
                NULL,                   //
                &commandLine[0],        //
                NULL,                   //
                NULL,                   //
                FALSE,                  //
                0,                      //
                NULL,                   //
                NULL,                   //
                &si,                    //STARTUPINFO
                &pi                     // PROCESS_INFORMATION
        ))
        {
            std::wcerr << L"CreateProcess failed. Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        
        DWORD exitCode;
        GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode);
        
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        return true;
}

